# Google app engine not accepting binary file upload anymore

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the kay framework for quite a while now but, since the last time I updated app engine, I can't manage to upload non pure ASCII files ...

the error I got is :

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

here is the full log :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Erwann:scrollshowPROD diwann$ python manage.py appcfg update
Running on Kay-2.0.0qa1
Compiling templates...
Now compiling templates in www/templates to www/templates_compiled.
Now compiling templates in user/templates to user/templates_compiled.
Now compiling templates in presentation/templates to presentation/templates_compiled.
Now compiling templates in /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/kay/auth/templates to /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/kay/auth/templates_compiled.
Now compiling templates in /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/presentation/templates to /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/presentation/templates_compiled.
Now compiling templates in /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/user/templates to /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/user/templates_compiled.
Now compiling templates in /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/www/templates to /Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/www/templates_compiled.
Finished compiling templates...
02:36 AM Host: appengine.google.com
02:36 AM Application: scrollshow; version: 1
02:36 AM 
Starting update of app: scrollshow, version: 1
02:36 AM Getting current resource limits.
02:36 AM Scanning files on local disk.
Could not guess mimetype for static/assets/themes/plimse/California beach/Repertoire temporaire pour combler un ancien nom de theme.  Using application/octet-stream.
02:37 AM Scanned 500 files.
Could not guess mimetype for static/assets/themes/plimse/California beach/Repertoire temporaire pour combler un ancien nom de theme.  Using application/octet-stream.
02:37 AM Cloning 430 static files.
02:37 AM Cloning 466 application files.
02:37 AM Uploading 3 files and blobs.
02:37 AM Missing File Path : static/assets/themes/plimse/textures/scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor_web.jpg
02:37 AM Missing File Path : static/assets/themes/plimse/textures/underPageBackgroundColor_web.jpg
02:37 AM Missing File Path : static/media/js/scrollshowReader.js
02:37 AM File Path : static/assets/themes/plimse/textures/scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor_web.jpg
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred. Aborting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2302, in DoUpload
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1579, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1536, in SendBatch
    payload,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
02:37 AM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    script.run()
  File "/Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/kay/lib/werkzeug/script.py", line 121, in run
    return func()
  File "/Users/diwann/Source/scrollshow/scrollshow-web/lexman/scrollshowPROD/kay/management/appcfg.py", line 58, in do_appcfg_passthru_argv
    result = app.Run()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2688, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4235, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3247, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml, yaml_file_basename)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3196, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2302, in DoUpload
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1579, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1536, in SendBatch
    payload,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

*Note that the "Missing File Path" part have been added by myself to kay to know which files caused the error*

It appears first that some caracters of my code were not allowed anymore and after I removed them all, I succeed to upload my app to app engine. 
But now, I need to upload an image, and it still complains it's not ASCII ... 
(this log says that it can not upload the file "scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor_web.jpg" because the first caracter is not ascii) ...

Is there something to set up in kay or app engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer on kay user mailing list. 
They said to use google_appengine/appcfg.py directly.

NB : here is the full command line I did :

> python /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/appcfg.py update  .