# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: google-app-engine

My themes has .js file and it used to work. But today when I commented out some lines of code, or just open and save it and update my app, i got this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The full error is

```
2014-06-22 14:52:01,388 ERROR appcfg.py:2487 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2328, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2466, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1401, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1360, in SendBatch
    payload,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
02:52 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5214, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5205, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2885, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4884, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3681, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3734, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3617, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2328, in DoUpload
    self._UploadMissingFiles(missing_files, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2466, in _UploadMissingFiles
    self.blob_batcher.Flush()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1401, in Flush
    self.SendBatch()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1360, in SendBatch
    payload,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
2014-06-22 14:52:03 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

My file is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27576887/StackOverFlow/charisma.js
I open and edit the file in VS 2012 
Please tell me what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So apparently that's an encoding problem: there's one or more characters in your code which are not being possible to decode at upload time. [Check sendBatch method at 1282](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py?spec=svn410&r=410)

If you can do without the problematic characters then you are good to go. [Otherwise, it seems that updating your server directly through appcfg.py in terminal makes it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971021/google-app-engine-not-accepting-binary-file-upload-anymore/15078706#15078706)

```
python appcfg.py update
```

Either way it'd be interesting to trace progress on this issue.

Comment: in case there are many .js file, it takes so much time to convert from uft-8 to shift-jis. I try to open C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\tools folder and find appcfg.py, but there is only 1 file named bulkload_client.py. There is appcfg.py in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine folder, but there is only a few lines of code in that file. I am using the latest GAE version 1.9.6. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The route is rather C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\. Check there.

Answer (score 0):

The file is saved as Unicode UTF-8 without signature.
I changed it to Japanese SHIft-JIS and it worked again.